VisualStudio WSL debugging: custom GDB command line?
Is there a way to tell Visual Studio (I use version 2022) to use a custom GDB command line, when attaching to a process run under WSL? E.g., something like
gdb -iex "set sysroot /" -p <pid>

which is needed to be able to debug a process run within an unprivileged namespace.

Based on my research and testing, you can set up Visual Studio to use GDB for debugging WSL processes by following these steps:

Go to the project properties and select the Debugging tab.
Under theDebugger to Launch section, select GDB (Remote Linux).
In the GDB
Command field, enter the path to the GDB command line you want to
use. For example, if you want to use the GDB command line with the
sysroot option set, you can enter "gdb-i -iex 'set sysroot /'".
In
the Remote Launch section, select WSL Remote Machine and choose the
WSL distribution you want to use.
Save the project properties and
start debugging.


Thank you!
Do you know what is the conditions when the "GDB (Remote Linux)" item is shown? In my case, I only see Local Windows Debugger, Remote Windows Debugger, Web Browser Debugger, and Web Service Debugger.

It requires Linux in  in the .vcxproj. But I still don't see how to attach to the already running process, which is an important part of the question.

I don't know where you are in. Did you open the Debug menu, select Attach to Process, and choose the WSL distribution and the process you want to attach to? Have you reached this step?
